# show list.blade.php in tab in another blade

Tags: php, laravel, tabs, laravel-blade

I want to put a list.blade.php into a tab in another blade(jobrole.blade) so that there are some tabs showing different blade-content within a blade

I managed to show the list but the tabs dissapear: i used @include

```
 @include('backpack::crud.list', array("crud" => $crud))
```

here some pics for u to see what i mean

[Tabs-pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql5wF.png)

[List is shown but no tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5VWT.png)

how can i prevent the tabs from dissapearing while showing list.blade.php

here is the jobrole.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">


            <div class="box box-default">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Role</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Accountabilities</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">PhysReqs</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                    {{--@dd(get_defined_vars());--}}
                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                        @include('backpack::crud.list', array("crud" => $crud))
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                        <a href="{{ backpack_url('accountability') }}">Accountability</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: please ask your question clearly. What you accept and what you receive...

Comment: have you tried including it in another place?what does it show